# How to deal with pseudo-compressibility of lattice Boltzmann method when you are calculating mass flux?

Tags: incompressible, lattice-boltzmann-methods

In lattice Boltzmann method, we have a concept, which is called **pseudo-compressibility** and it is defined based on the fact that LBM simulates incompressible flows by having small **Mach** number to ensure density fluctuations in time (or pressure fluctuations in time) are not that big. Note, that introduced **Mach** number here is just a numerical parameter calculated as:

$$Ma = \frac{u_{max}\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}}{\hat{c}_{s}}$$

Where $Ma$ is **Mach** number, $u_{max}$ is temporal maximum of velocity presents in the simulation, $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ are temporal and spatial discretization resolutions respectively, and $\hat{c}_{s} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is the lattice parameter. As a result pressure is calculated based on ideal gas equation as:

$$\Delta P = \Delta \rho c_{s}^{2}$$

Where $\Delta P = P - P_{\mathrm{ref}}$, $\Delta \rho = \rho - \rho_{f}$, and $c_{s} = \hat{c}_{s} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ is speed of sound in the lattice, and $\rho_{f}$ is known fluid density (e.g. for water it is 1000 $\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m}^{3}}$), and finally $\rho$ is instantaneous density, where we call $\Delta \rho$  density fluctuations. For small $Ma$ values, this fluctuations are smaller than 5%.

Now, let's define mass flux as for example in an arbitrary cut plane ($\Gamma$) of computational domain ($\Omega$) as:

$$M(t) = \int_{\Gamma} \rho \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t) \cdot d \mathscr{A}$$

Where $M(t)$ is mass flux, $\rho$ is **instantaneous** density, $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t)$ is velocity, and $d \mathscr{A}$ is surface differential form of $\Gamma$ cut plane. On the other hand, volumetric mass flux is defined as:

$$Q(t) = \int_{\Gamma} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t)\cdot d \mathscr{A}$$

Obviously: $M(t) \neq \rho_{f} Q(t)$. I know $M(t)$ and $\rho_{f} Q(t)$ must be close and their difference must be in the order of that 5% fluctuation, but I'm confused that if we want to calculate for example volumetric flux, which number should be used or reported? $Q(t)$ or $\frac{M(t)}{\rho_{f}}$? I appreciate if someone could explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both can be considered to be equally valid. In fact, asymptotically (with an infinite number of lattice) you will tend towards the incompressible athermal Navier-Stokes equations. In this limit, both measures of the flow should be equal.  If I were you, I would initially report the two. Then I would measure the difference between them as a measure of the impact of your pseudo-compressibility on your flow. Then, I think I would use the velocity-field alone to calculate the mass flux. Don't forget that your density is really there to act as a pseudo pressure in your equation of state and is not a measure of your real density.

I hope that makes sense.